# Не получается внести изменения в корзину на Django через ajax

Tags: ajax, django

Здравствуйте. У меня реализована корзина следующим образом:

```
class Cart(object):
def __init__(self, request):
    # Инициализация корзины пользователя
    self.session = request.session
    self.cupon_id = self.session.get('cupon_id')
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if not cart:
        # Сохраняем корзину пользователя в сессию
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    self.cart = cart

# Добавление товара в корзину пользователя или обновление количеста товара
def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                 'price': str(product.price)}
    if update_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
    self.save()

# Сохранение данных в сессию
def save(self):
    self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
    # Указываем, что сессия изменена
    self.session.modified = True

def remove(self, product):
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id in self.cart:
        del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

# Итерация по товарам
def __iter__(self):
    product_ids = self.cart.keys()
    products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
    for product in products:
        self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

    for item in self.cart.values():
        item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
        item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
        yield item


# Количество товаров
def __len__(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

def clear(self):
    del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
    self.session.modified = True
```

Она работает, но при обновление шаблона через ajax перестаёт работать следующий цикл:

```html
{% for item in cart %}
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

В результате чего сервер возвращает ошибку 500

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что ваш цикл в шаблоне никак не может отображать изменения которые произошли после отдачи страницы, т.к html отдаваемый клиенту в итоге - это просто разметка(читай текст), никак не привязанный к объекту (cart в вашем случае) на сервере.

За это отвечает шаблонизатор, почитайте подробнее об этом в документации Django.

В вашем случае, после обновления корзины у пользователя через ajax - руками обновлять html разметку на странице пользователя. Т.е отправить запрос на сервер с позициями корзины, в ответе ожидать позиции в корзине и с использованием javascript вставлять(обновлять) полученые данные в нужном месте.

[Документация шаблонизатора Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/)